# Google CSE Branding on IE Re-appearing on custom search Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-custom-search

I have chose to CSE Result Only look and feel in order to implement my box.

I did the branding of Google CS by attaching functions to onblur and onfocus. I found the code on a Demo by Google.

Everything works fine, but here is an annoying scheme on IE:

1. A user types in the box and searches
2. A user clicks on link that open in the current window
3. If he clicks back, the box shows the query and the box's background.

On different browsers the query is removed. 
My problem is how to either clear the box or remove the background.

IE is not running my codes (which works in my branding code) after the user clicks back.

Here is the Code I used to bind events.

```js
(function() {
  var f = document.getElementById('cse-search-box-form-id');

  if (f && f['cse-search-input-box-id']) {
    var q = f['cse-search-input-box-id'];
    var n = navigator;
    var l = location;
    var du = function(n, v) {
      var u = document.createElement('input');
      u.name = n;
      u.value = v;
      u.type = 'hidden';
      f.appendChild(u);
      return u;
    };
    var su = function(n, t, v, l) {
      if (!encodeURIComponent || !decodeURIComponent) {
        return;
      }
      var regexp = new RegExp('(?:[?&]' + n + '=)([^&#]*)');
      var existing = regexp.exec(t);
      if (existing) {
        v = decodeURIComponent(existing[1]);
      }
      var delimIndex = v.indexOf('://');
      if (delimIndex >= 0) {
        v = v.substring(delimIndex + '://'.length, v.length);
      }
      var v_sub = v.substring(0, l);
      while (encodeURIComponent(v_sub).length > l) {
        v_sub = v_sub.substring(0, v_sub.length - 1);
      }
      du(n, v_sub);
    };
    var pl = function(he) {
      var ti = 0,
        tsi = 0,
        tk = 0,
        pt;
      return function() {
        var ct = (new Date).getTime();
        if (pt) {
          var i = ct - pt;
          ti += i;
          tsi += i * i;
        }
        tk++;
        pt = ct;
        he.value = [ti, tsi, tk].join('j');
      };
    };
    var append = false;
    if (n.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
      var s = f.parentNode.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].nodeName == 'SCRIPT' &&
          s[i].attributes['src'] &&
          s[i].attributes['src'].nodeValue == unescape('http:\x2F\x2Fwww.google.com\x2Fcse\x2Fbrand?form=cse-search-box-form-id\x26inputbox=cse-search-input-box-id')) {
          append = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      append = true;
    }
    if (append) {

      var loc = document.location.toString();
      var ref = document.referrer;
      su('siteurl', loc, loc, 250);
      su('ref', loc, ref, 750);



      if (q.addEventListener) {
        q.addEventListener('keyup', pl(du('ss', '')), false);
      } else if (q.attachEvent) {
        q.attachEvent('onkeyup', pl(du('ss', '')));
      }
    }


    if (n.platform == 'Win32') {
      q.style.cssText = 'border: 0px ';
    }


    if (window.history.navigationMode) {
      window.history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
    }

    var b = function() {
      if (q.value == '') {
        q.style.background = '#fff url(http:\x2F\x2Fwww.google.com\x2Fcse\x2Fintl\x2Fen\x2Fimages\x2Fgoogle_custom_search_watermark.gif) 3.5% 80% no-repeat';
      }
    };

    var f = function() {
      q.style.background = '#fff';
    };

    q.onfocus = f;
    q.onblur = b;


    if (!/[&?]q=[^&]/.test(l.search)) {
      b();
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="search-bar-outer">
  <form onsubmit="return executeQuery();" id="cse-search-box-form-id">
    <div class="search-box-outer">
      <input type="text" id="cse-search-input-box-id" size="25" autocomplete="off"                       style="border: 0px;" class="search-input">
    </div>
    <div class="search-button-outer">
      <button type="submit" class="search-button"></button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/branding.js"></script>
</div>
```